# Clash of Clans: Upgrading heroes while in war

Tags: clash-of-clans

When buildings are getting upgraded, the upgrade only takes effect if it finishes before the attack phase of the war. I don't know what happens with heroes.
If my heroes finish they upgrade at the attack phase of a war, could I use them to attack the same war? Will they be the previous level or the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When heroes are upgrading:

- They cannot defend the village from regular attacks
- They will defend your village in war at the level they were when preparation phase finished
- They cannot be used to attack on war nor on regular attacks.

If your heroes upgrade gets finished on war attack phase

- You CAN use them to attack in war  but they will continue defending with the level they were when preparation phase finished

It looks confusing, but actually is pretty simple. You'll get used to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've also found out that, if the upgrade finishes during the attack phase of a war, they are available for those attacks.